# Typescript constructor for a class with dynamic properties

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-generics

Type 'typeof Md' is not assignable to type 'Model'.
Type 'Md' is not assignable to type 'Store'.

```
type Store<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:T[P]
}

interface Model {
    new <T>(data:T):Store<T>
}

const Md:Model = class<T>  {
    constructor(data:T) {
        Object.assign(this,data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't understand the implications of `Object.assign(this, data)` so doing this sort of thing always require some sort of `as` assertion.

`const Md: Model` says "I expect this `Md` variable to conform the the `Model` interface.  Whereas `const Md = (something) as Model` says "treat (something) as a `Model` even if it isn't".  You want the latter.

```
const Md = class <T> {
  constructor(data: T) {
    Object.assign(this, data)
  }
} as Model;
```

```
const obj = new Md({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

The resolved type for this instance `obj` is

```
const obj: Store<{
    a: number;
    b: number;
}>
```

Note that the type `Store<T>` in your example is the same as just `T`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w187AW)